# Возможно ли однозначно охарактеризовать такие понятия как "инструментальные средства разработки" и "прикладные программы" на Java?

Tags: java, терминология

[Читаю](https://www.ozon.ru/context/detail/id/31249554/) (стр 336)

> Аннотации предназначены в основном для использования в инструментальных
>   средствах разработки и развертывания прикладных программ на Java.

Возможно ли однозначно охарактеризовать такие понятия как "инструментальные средства разработки" и "прикладные программы" на `Java`?

Comment: первые, частный случай вторых

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В оригинальной книге:

> Although annotations are designed mostly for use by other development or deployment tools

`Development tools` или `Инструментальные средства разработки` это [Integrated development environment -
 IDE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integrated_development_environment) (IntelliJ IDEA, Eclipse, NetBeans etc)

`Deployment tools` или `Средства развертывания` это инструменты автоматизации сборки и развертывания приложений (Maven, Gradle, Ant etc)